# FileInput doesn't work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which opens a window dialog to browse a document in docx, doc, txt format and which works perfect in case of chrome but in IE11 it fails to load the uploaded document. I tried wrapping the input in a form which didn't work either. How can I make it work in IE11 ?

```js
 function OpenImportDialogue() {        
        $("#fileinput").click();
        }
 $("#fileinput").change(function() {       
        readDocument(this);
    });
   function readDocument(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                var streamType = TXTextControl.streamType.PlainText;
                // set the StreamType based on the lower case extension
                switch (input.value.split('.').pop().toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'doc':
                        streamType = TXTextControl.streamType.MSWord;
                        break;
                    case 'docx':
                        streamType = TXTextControl.streamType.WordprocessingML;
                        break;
                    case 'rtf':
                        streamType = TXTextControl.streamType.RichTextFormat;
                        break;
                    case 'txt':
                        streamType = TXTextControl.streamType.PlainText;
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("doc, docx, txt and rtf are the supported document Types");

                }
                // load the document beginning at the Base64 data (split at comma)
                var lines =  e.target.result.split(',')[0];
                if(lines.includes('base64'))
                    TXTextControl.loadDocument(streamType, e.target.result.split(',')[1]);
                else
                    TXTextControl.Load(streamType,  "IA==");
                $(input).prop("value", "");
            };
            // read the file and convert it to Base64
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class='ribbon-button ribbon-button-big' onclick='OpenImportDialogue()' >
```

Thank you

Comment: What does "*Doesn't work*" means? Do you have an error in the console? I see one horrible 90s thing you are doing: instead of getting the file's extension from the `input.value`, extract it from `input.files[0].name`, and don't get  also be aware that it may not be the correct file extension, but I don't think this is your issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I am not seeing any error in console strangely.

Comment: Ah I think I see it now, do you use a polyfill for Array#includes? IIRC IE doesn't support this method.

Comment: Nah! I didnt use pollyfill.

Comment: And it fixed the problem? One is available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill

Comment: Yeah. Thank you for looking into it. Changed the code to some extent and it works now in IE, Chrome, Edge and Mozilla